# Property [name] does not exist in this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy en laravel 7 y usando el paquete de roles y usuarios de Spatie, llamado permissions.
Necesito hacer un crud que me permita realizar la mantención de la relación de usuarios y su rol respectivo. Este crud debe permitir:

1. Listar los usuarios y su rol asignado (cada usuario puede tener un solo rol). 2. Crear una asociación de un rol a un usuario.
2. Modificar una relación de usuario y rol existente.
3. Eliminar una relación de usuario y un rol.

Para el caso de (1) Listar los usuarios y sus roles, estoy enviando lo siguiente a la vista:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class AdminUsurol extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme="bootstrap";
    public $search;

    public function render()
    {       
        $userroles = User::with('roles')->get();
        return view('livewire.admin-usurol', compact('userroles'));
    }

    public function limpia_page(){
        $this->reset('page');
    }
}
```

En la vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
@if ($userroles->count())
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Rol</th>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @forelse ($userroles as $userrole)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$userrole->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$userrole->roles->name}}</td>
                        <td width="10px">
                            <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('usurol.edit', $userrole)}}">Modificar</a>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10px">
                            <form action="{{route('usurol.destroy',$userrole)}}" method="POST">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">No hay usuarios asociados a roles registrados</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforelse
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        
    </div>            
@else
    <div class="card-body">
        <p>No hay coincidencias</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Pero al ejecutar me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si imprimo lo que se manda a la vista, tengo:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1481 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\User {#1468 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\User {#1469 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\User {#1470 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Abriendo el primer elemento:

```
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1481 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\User {#1468 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #hidden: array:2 [▶]
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "users"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "User1"
        "email" => "user1@user1.com"
        "email_verified_at" => null
        "password" => "$2y$10$Uuf3Ml7cVgx54N.P06oGeul.ytDkArX2M9n2rEJVOg/yQz1qTHYvG"
        "flg_vigencia" => 1
        "remember_token" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-02-02 15:50:37"
        "updated_at" => "2021-02-02 15:50:37"
      ]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "roles" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1485 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => Spatie\Permission\Models\Role {#1477 ▼
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: "roles"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:6 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "name" => "Admin"
                "flg_vigencia" => 1
                "guard_name" => "web"
                "created_at" => "2021-02-02 15:50:37"
                "updated_at" => "2021-02-02 15:50:37"
              ]
              #original: array:9 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #classCastCache: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▶]
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #hidden: []
              #visible: []
              #fillable: []
              -permissionClass: null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
      -roleClass: null
      -permissionClass: null
    }
    1 => App\Models\User {#1469 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\User {#1470 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Mi consulta es de qué forma debo acceder a la información del rol en la vista de modo que se pueda desplegar?

Si no pongo la información del rol en la vista, queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en este segmento de código:

```
@forelse ($userroles as $userrole)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$userrole->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$userrole->roles->name}}</td>
```

Puesto que *estás asumiendo* que vas a poder leer directamente en *ese nivel* los `name` de los roles.

Lo anterior por supuesto no es posible pues los datos de cada rol son objetos que están o existen dentro de una colección anidada a la cual llegamos por medio de la clave *roles*

Entonces deberás iterar por segunda vez dentro del *forelse* de esta forma:

```
/*
    El resto de tu código
*/
@foreach($userrole->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
    //Las demás propiedades que quieras mostrar de los roles
@endforeach
/*
    El resto de tu código
*/
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM, funcionó con tu indicación. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.